# How to add twig template for OwlCarousel format?

Tags: views, 8

I am working with drupal8. I have created a views with owlCarousel format.I want to add twig template for this carousel views.How to name this twig template?

Comment: Have you already enabled [Twig Debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)? If not, enable it. It will print you template suggestion into your HTML as HTML comments.

Comment: Yes ..i have enabled.This is the template suggestion "owlcarousel-views.html.twig" i have got from source.And my view name is "expert_talk".I dont know how to name this theme file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rename it like this: **owlcarousel-views--expert-talk.html.twig**